# How to setup Application Insights with Asp.Net-Core HealthChecks

Tags: azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-2.2

Asp.Net Core released version 2.2 and together with it comes HealthChecks feature. ([Read more](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/12/04/asp-net-core-2-2-available-today/)). One of the features it has is to push health check results to Azure Application Insights. But I have not found any way how to see those results in Azure portal. To send the results I am using following extension:

```
        services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddSqlServer("...")
            .AddApplicationInsightsPublisher();
```

Is there a way to view those Health Check reports in Application Insights?

EDIT 1: I took the example from official [github docs](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#healthcheck-push-results).

EDIT 2: If I go to the Azure portal query analytics I see following results:

Querying `requests`:

[image]

Querying `customEvents`

[image]

here: `GET /health` is my healthCheck endpoint. By querying `requests` logs I can see if health check failed or not, but I want to see more details about each health check, also I don't think I need any extension for this, so I don't understand what `AddApplicationInsightsPublisher()` actually does.

Comment: Where is AddApplicationInsightsPublisher() defined and what does it do? I am not aware of any automatic way to publish result to application insights - Application Insights continue to collect requests as usual.

Comment: Please see this for more info: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#healthcheck-push-results It is defined as extansion method to the `AddHealthChecks` service and it should push health check results to Application insights

Comment: Once published to Application Insights, you can query them in the related resource by using Analytics (customEvents) or Metrics (Custom).

Comment: @StefanPrugg I am not getting any customEvents with health check information. The only place where I can see it is in `requests` logs, but there I can only know if request succeded or failed, I would like to see which part of health check is failing exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently an issue with the registration of the publisher (HealthCheckPublisherHostedService) which will be fixed for aspnet core 3.
Currently the workaround is to manually register correctly the class :

```cs
services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddApplicationInsightsPublisher();

// This is a hack to fix an issue with the AddApplicationInsightsPublisher() call above
services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IHostedService), typeof(HealthCheckPublisherOptions).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckPublisherHostedService")));
```

See : https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/639

Answer (score 1):

It looks the health events are sent to Application Insights as custom events using TravkEvent api. You can see them in Analytics or Search in the portal.